# Azure role ( WCF services ) is not logging trace information

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-diagnostics

I'm hosting a bunch of WCF services in worker role, which I'm deploying to Azure. Problem is that the standard Trace logging isn't showing up in the Azure storage tables.

In code - I'm using

```
Trace.TraceInformation("Something")
```

In the .csdef I've got the default

```
<Imports>
    <Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />
</Imports>
```

In the .csfg I've got

```
   <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" value="CONNECTION_STRING_THAT_WORKS_FOR_OTHER_ROLE" />
  </ConfigurationSettings>
```

And in the wadcfg I've got

```
  <Logs bufferQuotaInMB="1024" scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M" scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter="Verbose" />
```

This setup works fine for a worker role that I'm deploying too, which logs nicely in the WADLogsTable. But this one isn't. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved this later by modifying not the Azure project but the underlying webrole:

1 - Add a file webrole.cs to the project, having this inside:

```
public class WebRole : RoleEntryPoint
{
    public override bool OnStart()
    {    
        return base.OnStart();
    }
}
```

2 - And this is the app.config of the same project:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace>
      <listeners>
        <add name="AzureDiagnostics" type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=2.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
          <filter type="" />
        </add>
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

That fixed it for us

Answer (score 0):

How are you setting up the DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, and in which process are you doing the Trace.TraceInformation calls?  I usually see this in DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener is in the app.config, but the Trace.TraceInformation calls are happening in some other process.  You have to setup the DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener in the .config file (or in code via TraceListeners.Add) for the process where your Trace.TraceInformation calls are being made from.  If that doesn't resolve the issue then there are three approaches I generally take to troubleshoot this issue:

1. Is it a problem with your code writing Trace statements?  RDP to the Azure VM and setup a simple TextWriterTraceListener to write to a file - [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk36c28t(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk36c28t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
2. Is it a problem with traces not being picked up by Windows Azure Diagnostics agent (ie. the problem I describe above about the DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener not being registered)?  Use the table2csv tool in AzureTools at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2013/08/26/azuretools-the-diagnostic-utility-used-by-the-windows-azure-developer-support-team.aspx to look at the WADLogs TSF files.
3. Is it a problem of the traces being collected, but not uploaded to storage?  Use the same table2csv tool but look at the MAEvent tables.  These tables log the transfer of diagnostic data to storage.